# LinkedList sorting a-z

Tags: c++, class, append, structure, project

Requirements for this function: If the full name (both the first and last name) is not equal to any full name currently in the list then add it and return true. Elements should be added according to their last name. Elements with the same last name should be added according to
their first names. Otherwise, make no change to the list and return false (indicating that the name is already in the list).

```
//this function add nodes to the list
//return true if fullname isn't in the list. Else return false if fullname is in the list.
//should be added according to last name.
bool OnlineDating::makeMatch(const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName, const OnlineType& value)
{
    Node* p = head;
    //are these nodes already set to firstName and lastName in this function
    Node first;
    Node last;
    Node* temp = nullptr;
    //if the list is empty just insert the fullname and value to the list
    if (p == nullptr) {
        //add values to the empty list
        insertToRear(firstName, lastName, value);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        // so this loop is to check if fullname is in the list but first sort in alphebetial order
        //sure its added in alphebetical order
        //traverse the list after knowing where head is
        while (p != nullptr) {

            //checking to make sure theres at least another node in the list
            if (p->next != nullptr) {
                //its not going through ig loop?
                //these are used to check and alphebetically selected names
                if (p->last > p->next->last) {
                    insertToRear(p->first, p->last, p->value);
                    p->next = temp;

                    return true;
                }
                else if (p->next->last > p->last) {
                    insertToRear(p->first, p->last, p->value);
                    p->next = temp;

                    return true;
                }
                //check if full name is already in the list
                if (p->last == p->next->last) {
                    insertToRear(p->first, p->last, p->value);
                    p->next = temp;

                    return true;
                }
                else if (p->first > p->next->first) {
                    insertToRear(p->first, p->last, p->value);
                    p->next = temp;

                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    //returns false if it passes through these  checks
                    return false;
                }
            }
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main.cpp

```
int main()
{

    OnlineDating clippersGonnaClip;
    clippersGonnaClip.makeMatch("Kawhi", "Leonard", 2);
    clippersGonnaClip.makeMatch("Paul", "George", 13);
    clippersGonnaClip.makeMatch("Ivica", "Zubac", 40);
    clippersGonnaClip.makeMatch("Reggie", "Jackson", 1);
    clippersGonnaClip.makeMatch("Patrick", "Beverley", 21);
    for (int n = 0; n < clippersGonnaClip.howManyMatches(); n++) {
        string first;
        string last;
        int val;
        clippersGonnaClip.confirmMatch(n, first, last, val);
        cout << first << " " << last << " " << val << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

honestly, I just want to create a ptr that will point to each node. Check as long as that node isn't pointing to nullptr, and sort the LinkedList in alphabetical order. finally link the nodes together using my *temp. Why won't it let me go through the if statements every time I compile I get a negative number? Every other function works for this program except this makeMatch(...).

Comment: Start simpler: Begin by creating your list and make sure all nodes are in it. Then create a function to swap two nodes, and test it for multiple cases (two first nodes, two last nodes, two nodes in the middle). Then you can start looking at the sorting.

Comment: Or, you know, use a standard C++ container (preferably `std::vector`) and `std::sort` instead.

Comment: shouldn't the list already be sorted? You only use `firstName` and `lastName` if the list is empty?

Comment: using a vector makes sense, but I can only use a data structure for this assignment and am limited to a template he provides. Alan, I want the list to be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: If you only ever insert in the correct position for a sorted list then the list will always be sorted. Sorting linked lists is a nightmare, the usual approach is to create a new list and use an insertion sort

Comment: yes, I'm going to try the usual approach thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the requirements says anything about the data types you need to use. In this case using std::set makes most sense.
By providing a comparison operation on persons and a set you can guarantee uniqueness. Like this :

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct person_t
{
    std::string name;
    std::string last_name;
    unsigned int age;
};

bool operator<(const person_t& lhs, const person_t& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.last_name == rhs.last_name)
        return lhs.name < rhs.name;

    return lhs.last_name < rhs.last_name;
}

int main()
{
    // set will ensure all persons are unique
    std::set<person_t> persons;
    persons.insert({ "Kawhi", "Leonard", 2 });
    persons.insert({ "Paul", "George", 13 });
    persons.insert({ "Ivica", "Zubac", 40 });
    persons.insert({ "Reggie", "Jackson", 1 });
    persons.insert({ "Patrick", "Beverley", 21 });

}
```

Comment: I actually can't use a global struct, but the implementation of how your checking the list helps me. Thank you for this!

Comment: Well I would make this set a member of the OnlineDating class. Then all functions within that class can use it. But this was mainly to show you that a lot of datastructures already have a (very well tested) implementation in the standard library ready for you to reuse.

Comment: Yes, appreciate that comment! Will look into that